# How to check how many times a class property was set with a specific value?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, properties, count

Is there any possible way in determining how many times a class property was set with a specific `value` ?

Comment: You can write in the setter code, that counts this.

Comment: Could you tell initial reason, why do you want to do this?

Comment: i have a class with almost 15 properties, the value of these properties changes some times. for example if the value becomes "1" for a property i want the count to be one . when the value changes to something else and returns back to  one i ant the count to be 2 and so on, And this need to  be done for almost all the properties

Comment: @VishnuBabu: I understand, how your question is stated. I'm wondering, what do you plan to do with that count?

Comment: 'Time6' is a property 'Time630' is another property, they are bound to DataGrid columns...The code is set in such a way that when ever the property changes (possible values for properties are " " and "1") they are inserted to the WPF datagrid, in the design part i set trigger properties if the value is " " the cell colour doesn't changes and if "1" the cell colour changes of the datagrid row, At the end i want the total coloured cells in the datagrid for each column i.e.,the count of "1" will be same as the coloured cells for each column.

Comment: using the setter property could create  large amount of coding . i was thinking if there was some other way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using settter as well, Lake a look into the following snippet

```
class myClass
    {
        private string _MyStringVar;
        public string specificWord = "word";
        public int SpecificCount = 0;
        public string MyStringVar
        {
            get { return _MyStringVar; }
            set
            {
                bool isChanged = false;
                if (_MyStringVar != specificWord) { isChanged = true; }
                // check for old value to confirm value changed
                _MyStringVar = value;
                if (value == specificWord && isChanged) { SpecificCount++; }
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: need to check whether the value changed also.

Comment: @Shelvin : Correct point, take a look into the updates

Answer (score 2):

you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this purpose

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx